# To find subscript index in strsplit function

Tags: r, mapreduce, bigdata

How to find subscript index number when we use strsplit() function in R.
My output is

```
N712SW|2008      8 
N772SW|2008      19 
N428WN|2008      8
```

what will be my output if I split by tab first next split by |

I want to know subscript after using

```
split <- unlist(strsplit(line, "\t"))
  key <- split[[1]]
  deptDelay <- as.numeric(split[[2]])
 if (!(identical(lastKey, "")) & (!(identical(lastKey, key)))) {
    keySplit <- unlist(strsplit(lastKey, "\\|"))
```

Comment: What is `lastKey`? You are missing a `}` to close the `if` statement. What is your expected output given the sample data? Please make a [small reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1478381).

Comment: The double brackets on `split[[1]]` and `split[[2]]` are not needed, as you have already unlisted it. Also, I guess this doesn't require expertise on `mapreduce` or `bigdata`...?